# Display a selected option from a drop down list into a box using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

Hey I have a working drowpdown list in a form (using javascript) and want to display the output of the selected option (cat) into a box as id.

Both cat and id are in the same table (kernel).

Could someone please help me?

```
<form action="dropdown.php" method="POST">
  <?php
    $sth = $dbhandle->prepare("SELECT cat FROM kernel");
    $sth->execute();
    $results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<select name='cat'>";
    foreach($results as $row) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['cat'] . "'>" . $row['cat'] . "</option>";
    }    
    echo "</select>";
  ?>
</form>
```

Comment: are you using jQuery (have a look at the `change` event) or do you need vanilla javascript (have a look at the `onChange` event)?

Comment: i need vanilla javascript

Comment: i can't find the optioni want on his profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to hook into the `onChange` event of the `select` box

HTML:

```
<form action="dropdown.php" method="POST">
  <select name='cat' id="cat_select" onChange="outputValue(this)">
    <option value='cat1'>cat1</option>
    <option value='cat2'>cat2</option>
    <option value='cat3'>cat3</option>
    <option value='cat4'>cat4</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS:

```
function outputValue(item){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = item.value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X663R/

EDIT: below is php inclusive code

```
<form action="dropdown.php" method="POST">
  <?php
    $sth = $dbhandle->prepare("SELECT cat FROM kernel");
    $sth->execute();
    $results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<select name='cat' id='cat_select' onChange='outputValue(this)'>";
    foreach($results as $row) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['cat'] . "'>" . $row['cat'] . "</option>";
    }    
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='output' name='output' />";
  ?>
</form>
<script>
function outputValue(item){
    document.getElementById('output').value = item.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is what i used for my onchage event "echo "<select name='cat'   id='cat_select' onChange='outputValue(this)'>";" but it does nothing

Comment: also is there a way to display it into a text box? Please

Comment: you mean like an `input` box? 
you'll need to have the javascript added to the page and the `output` element there

Comment: here is an updated jsfiddle using an `input` of type `text` http://jsfiddle.net/X663R/1/

Comment: sorry for being a pain but could you please do it with the code i'm using as well becuae i can't get it to work with mine. Nothing happens :(